# Insert base64 string into MySQL LONGBLOB.

Tags: php, mysql, binary, base64, blob

I have a base64 (Image) string that I need to save on a MySQL data base as data type binary, LONGBLOB. The string is over 200,000 characters. The string is saved in a PHP variable.

I understand that this is not recommended, but I need some input on how it can be done. It has to be done in pure PHP. The base64 string is send through AJAX POST XMLHttpRequest.

Thanks.

Comment: Less than 200k, easy peasy, you could just add it as a string without problems. If they become _much_ bigger [see how to handle blobs](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Working-With-BLOBs-P554.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) might be what you are looking for:

```
 UPDATE colum SET img=LOAD_FILE('/tmp/file') WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: Can I use LOAD_FILE with a base64 string? I don't have a image file, only a base64 string.

Comment: You can use it with any kind of file. You simply need to store your base64 encoded string in the file.

Comment: Well that would be great. But how do I create a file in PHP and then how would I insert my base64 string? Is the file like a virtual memory file?